# Ayuda con implementación de Function strip_tags

Tags: php, html

Saludos chicos poseo el siguiente caso:
Estoy tratando de aplicar la fuction strip_tags a un dato que estoy recuperando de una base de datos mysql, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php $motivo = strip_tags($row['motivo_rechazo']);
```

Y la salida que estoy tratando de implementar es la siguiente:

```
<?php $statuspago = '<div class="text-center w-70 mx-auto alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-toggle="popover" title="RECHAZADO" data-content="Su pago fue rechazado, por el siguiente motivo: '.$motivo.'.">
             RECHAZADO  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
           </div>';
```

Pero en el resultado esta mostrando el popover con las etiquetas HTML con las que se guardo el dato $motivo en la base de datos MYSQL, alguna idea de como puedo solucionar este caso que he presentado.

Comment: tu `$motivo` actualmente es `<b>este es el motivo </b>` y lo que quieres es que devuelva solamente `este es el motivo` en negrita por ejemplo?

Comment: Si de hecho el motivo es algo como esto:  `<p>este es el motivo </p>`

Comment: De hecho en mi caso me serviria tanto quitar las etiquetas html como tambien reconocerlas en mi salida, cualquiera me serviria..!

Comment: Simplemente quítale el strip_tags, al pasarlo `<?php $motivo = $row['motivo_rechazo'];` al pasarlo en el html el navegador se encargará

Comment: Alli esta el detalle, dejandolo o quitandolo la salida en el navegador muestra `<p>este es el motivo </p>`